# Add to Cart - Chrome Extension Experiment

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I currently just got into making Chrome Extensions using mainly JQuery to run all my functions besides the manifest file.  I decided to try to make an active extension that would add a product to cart off of the store.nike.com to see what I could accomplish.

I came a long ways and, for the most part have everything working besides the actual `'add to cart'` feature.

How it works:

Person enters a shoe size in my popup.html, from their once the user lands on a page for a nike shoe, it will grab local stored shoe size and place into a value that gets submitted to the nike site's form.  Then using a `trigger('click')` event, submits.  Here is the issue, it tells me `"Select a Shoe Size"`

Check it out:

http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/lunarglide-5-running-shoe/pid-726047/pgid-726952 this is the product I am testing this out on.

Background Script that runs upon load of this page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    checkForData();

    $('.add-to-cart').trigger('click');
});
function checkForData()
{
    $('ul.footwear li').removeClass("selectBox-selected");
    chrome.storage.local.get('value', function (results) {
        a[rel$="\:'+results.value+'"]').html());
        $('ul.footwear').find('a').filter(function(idx, el){
            return $.trim($(this).text()) == $.trim(results.value);
        }).closest('li').addClass('selectBox-selected');
        $("a.footwear span.selectBox-label").text("(" + results.value +")");
    });
}
```

Here is what happens:  in the `ul.footwear` it removes the default `selectedBox-selected` - this if the default shoe size which is none. Next I run through chrome storage for local var and filter it through sites list of shoe sizes for the proper one.  Once found(or returned true) it will give it the `selectBox-selected` class as if someone clicked that associated shoe size.  From their I display it on the div which contains `Size`.  Finally I run a click event on the `add to cart`.

Unfortunately, it just wont work that way.  I get the error `"Select a Size"`.  Something else is up and I was hoping someone could give me insight on maybe what this might be, or point me in the right direction.

This is only an educational experiment.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution to this ?

Answer (score 2):

You are not writing a script to take advantage of poor kids trying to get Jordans are you?Open source the script on github and I'll try to help you.